# Pronoun positions in "let you ask me questions"

Tags: grammaire, ordre-des-mots, constructions-causatives

> I will let you ask me questions.

Is the correct translation

> Je vais vous laisser me poser des questions.

or

> Je vais vous me laisser poser des questions.

I'm not sure what the position of "me" should be in this case, in particular whether it should go before or after the verb "laisser".

Comment: Definitively the first one, «Je vais vous me laisser poser des questions.» isn't french at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct adverb location is:

> Je vais vous laisser **me** poser des questions.

though I'd rather say:

> Je vous laisserai me poser des question.

or simply:

> Vous pourrez me poser des question.